# C++ templates and virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, visitor-pattern

Say I have a hierarchy of classes:

```
class Animal;
class Cat: public Animal;
class Dog: public Animal;
```

Those classes are not templated. I have another parallel hierarchy of templated classes:

```
template<class T> class Drawer;
template<class T> class CatDrawer: public Drawer<T>;
template<class T> class DogDrawer: public Drawer<T>;
```

I would like to write the following:

```
class Animal{
    template<class T>
    virtual shared_ptr<Drawer<T>> create_drawer() = 0;
};
```

to allow each of the derived classes to create their templated version.

I know that C++ doesn't allow this, and I understand why. However, is there a nice way to simulate this behaviour?

I had a look at the following options:

1) I could template `Animal` itself:

```
template<class T>
class Animal{
    virtual shared_ptr<Drawer<T>> create_drawer() = 0;
};
```

I don't want to do that because the only point of this would be to support the creation of the drawer instances, and that would pollute a big part of the code which doesn't need template otherwise.

2) Curiously Recursive Template Pattern. I feel like this could work, however this would prevent me from creating a container of pointers on `Animal`.

3) Use a visitor; this would allow to separate the call `create_drawer()` in two parts, one on `Animal` which would record the fact that we want to create a Drawer& , and one on the visitor, which would create the templated drawer in a non virtual way.

```
class Animal{
    virtual void accept(DrawerCreatorVisitor v) = 0;
};
class Dog: public Animal{
    virtual void accept(DrawerCreatorVisitor v){
        v.visit(*this);
    };
}
...
class DrawerCreatorVisitor{
public:
    template<class T>
    shared_ptr<Drawer<T>> make_drawer(Animal& animal){
        animal.accept(*this); // double dispatch which will set the to_create member
        if(to_create == _dog)
            return shared_ptr<Drawer<T>>(new DogDrawer<T>(static_cast<Dog&>(animal)));
        if(to_create == _cat)
            return shared_ptr<Drawer<T>>(new CatDrawer<T>(static_cast<Cat&>(animal)));
    };

    void visit(Dog dog){
        to_create = _dog;
    };
    void visit(Cat cat){
        to_create = _cat;
    };
private:
    enum Drawable {_dog, _cat};
    Drawable to_create;
};
```

This seems to work; the calling syntax is ok:

```
DrawerCreatorVisitor dcv;
shared_ptr<Drawer<int>> dcv.make_drawer<int>(the_dog);
```

Can you see any drawback / any way to improve this? Also, I haven't really found loads on the subject, does that mean that my initial design is wrong? Many thanks :)

Comment: Why not just have a `virtual Draw() = 0` method on `Animal` ?

Comment: because given a collection of Animals, I need to create all the drawers before starting drawing anything